# Display HTML String in a Browser

Tags: java, swing, browser, javafx

I am working on a project and have embedded a [JavaFx Browser](https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/javafx_browser_as_a_ready) in a java application. Now, I would like to display some contents in the Browser.

I wanted to know that is there a way to display the contents through a string that contains HTML tags. I do not want to create a HTML file and the display the contents.

I was looking for something like JTextPane.

Comment: not sure i understand your question, if you already have an embedded browser setup, why use JTextPane? well, anyways, if you simply need a small thing that displays html you can use JLabel. does do myLabel.setText( "<html><b>this is bold text</b>" );

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I could not investigate that JavaFX Browser Netbeans Module in depth. But if it is using a [JavaFX WebView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html) control internally then you can load String value containing HTML page (or tag) via WebView's WebEngine. See the [WebEngine API](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html) for different content loadings. That Netbeans Module should have some interface API allowing this.

The method you want is [webView.getEngine().loadContent(htmlString)](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#loadContent(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the < to &lt, followed by a semicolon, and change the > to &gt, followed by a semicolon.

Just like I did to type this answer.

Answer (score 0):

When creating the "Scene" and adding it to the JFXPanel you want to put it in the JavaFX thread by using Platform.runLater :

```
 import javafx.application.Platform;
 import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;

    String HTML_TO_SEND = GetHTML();

    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
  browser = new WebView();
  webEngine = browser.getEngine();
  webEngine.loadContent(HTML_TO_SEND);

  browser.setVisible(true);
  Scene scene = new Scene(browser);
    jfxPanel.setScene(scene);


        }
  });
```

You can then add the jfxPanel to your Swing stuff as usual.